# How to store 3 key by index per row PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

i have problem with array, i have 3 array and i wont to merge into one by row index

```
$tahun = array(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014);
$status = array("akademi","instansi","umum","pending","pass");
$total = array(2,1,3,4,5);
```

i want this array into want like this

```
array(
0 => array(2010,"akademi",2),
1 => array(2011,"instansi",1),
2 => array(2012,"umum",3),
3 => array(2013,"pemding",4),
4 => array(2014,"pass",5),

);
```

but when i use array_merge_recursive() the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015
    [1] => 2016
    [2] => 2017
    [3] => 2018
    [4] => 2019
    [5] => 2019
    [6] => 2019
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 1
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 3
    [12] => 2
    [13] => 1
    [14] => akademisi
    [15] => instansi pemerintah
    [16] => umum
    [17] => umum
    [18] => akademisi
    [19] => instansi pemerintah
    [20] => umum
)
```

Comment: Why don't you create simple foreach loop and do that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with `null` as the callback...

```
$combined = array_map(null, $tahun, $status, $total);
```

from the manual...

> NULL can be passed as a value to callback to perform a zip operation
>   on multiple arrays. If only array1 is provided, array_map() will
>   return the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `foreach` loop:

```
$res = [];
foreach($tahun as $ind=>$val){
    $res[$ind] = [$val, $status[$ind], $total[$ind]];
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/McJj7)**